# The method 'data' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'. Try making the call conditional (using '?.') . How to solve?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
questionModel.question = questionSnapshot.data()["question"];
```

// The method 'data' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'.
Try making the call conditional (using '?.')

```
/// shuffling the options
List<String> options = [
  questionSnapshot.data()["option1"],
  questionSnapshot.data()["option2"],
  questionSnapshot.data()["option3"],
  questionSnapshot.data()["option4"]
];
options.shuffle();

questionModel.option1 = options[0];
questionModel.option2 = options[1];
questionModel.option3 = options[2];
questionModel.option4 = options[3];
questionModel.correctAnswer = questionSnapshot.data()["correctAnswer"];
questionModel.answered = false;
```

Comment: It would be easier if you include full model class, as for the error message, it is possible to get null while reading question, you can check null and then use `!`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error message says, calling `questionSnapshot.data()` can return `null` and you can't call further operations on that.

You'll want to check if the `data()` method returns null before processing the questions, for example with:

```
var data = questionSnapshot.data();
if (data != null) {
  List<String> options = [
    data["option1"],
    data["option2"],
    data["option3"],
    data["option4"]
  ];
  options.shuffle();
  ...
```